# In flutter, tabbar occupied appbar's space

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

I'm junior flutter developer.

I'd like to make a tabBar just below appBar.

So, I just add tabBar to appBar's bottom field.

Everything looks like well... before the screen was displayed...

My code is as follows.

```
// tab_view
class TabViewExample extends BaseView<TabViewExampleController> {
  final CustomTabController _tabController = Get.find();

  @override
  PreferredSizeWidget? appBar(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomAppBar(
      appBarTitleText: TextValues.preDiagnosisAppBarText,
      appBarTitleAlign: TextAlign.start,
      tabBar: TabBar(
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
        isScrollable: true,
        controller: _tabController.tabController,
        tabs: _tabController.tabList,
        unselectedLabelColor: AppColors.skyDarkColor,
        labelColor: AppColors.colorPrimary,
        labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: AppValues.margin_12.sp,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget body(BuildContext context) {
    return TabBarView(
      controller: _tabController.tabController,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Text('first tap'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('second tap'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
// base_view
abstract class BaseView<Controller extends BaseController>
    extends GetView<Controller> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> globalKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  final Logger logger = DioProvider.logger;

  Widget body(BuildContext context);

  PreferredSizeWidget? appBar(BuildContext context);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: annotatedRegion(context),
    );
  }

  Widget annotatedRegion(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        //Status bar color for android
        statusBarColor: statusBarColor(),
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: pageScaffold(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget pageScaffold(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //sets ios status bar color
      backgroundColor: pageBackgroundColor(),
      key: globalKey,
      appBar: appBar(context),
      body: pageContent(context),
    );
  }

  Widget pageContent(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: body(context),
    );
  }

}
```

```
// custom_appbar
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String appBarTitleText;
  final List<Widget>? actions;
  final bool isBackButtonEnabled;
  final Color? backgroundColor;
  final TextAlign appBarTitleAlign;
  final TabBar? tabBar;

  CustomAppBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.appBarTitleText,
    this.actions,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.isBackButtonEnabled = true,
    this.appBarTitleAlign = TextAlign.center,
    this.tabBar,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => AppBar().preferredSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.appBarColor,
      centerTitle: appBarTitleAlign == TextAlign.center ? true : false,
      elevation: 0,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: isBackButtonEnabled,
      actions: actions,
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: AppColors.appBarIconColor),
      title: AppBarTitle(
        text: appBarTitleText,
        textAlign: appBarTitleAlign,
      ),
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: tabBar,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With above code, the screen is like below image.
[image]

There is no error message of overflow in my logcat.

Which part of code is wrong...?

Please help me.

Comment: Can you include CustomAppBar codes please

Comment: @KaushikChandru I edited question with CustomAppBar!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but can you try this please in CustomAppBar add `toolbarHeight: kToolbarHeight,`

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      toolbarHeight: kToolbarHeight, //<--add this line
      backgroundColor: AppColors.appBarColor,
      centerTitle: appBarTitleAlign == TextAlign.center ? true : false,
      elevation: 0,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: isBackButtonEnabled,
      actions: actions,
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: AppColors.appBarIconColor),
      title: AppBarTitle(
        text: appBarTitleText,
        textAlign: appBarTitleAlign,
      ),
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: tabBar,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: As you can see in added contents, I've already tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: I see that you added it to the bottom of AppBar

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Scaffold` with `SafeArea` widget.

```dart
  return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
```

Comment: i tried this solution. but nothing is changed... ;)

Comment: Can you try flutter clean and rebuild the app. Also if there any parent widget using appbar, wrap the parent widget with safeArea

Comment: In my baseView code, the gestureDetector widget is root parent widget. So, i wrapped it with safeArea like your advise but nothing was changed..

Comment: does this issue happen on specific device or all

Answer (score 0):

It is not a cool answer, but I solved this problem.

My solution is not using CustomAppBar widget.

Just using default Flutter AppBar shows tabbar normally.